# Is there a non-contact temperature sensing technology that can measure the temperature of something emersed in water/other liquids?

Tags: sensor, temperature

It's pretty much all said in the title...

I want to get the temperature of a surface that my device is moving past. The surface may be as cold as -55°C. I was thinking about non-contact thermometer solutions to save myself some mechanical work in designing something to keep a thermometer touching the surface as I pass it (not a flat surface in the slightest, and not a set distance away).

My first thought was a cheap IR thermometer. However, while it would be perfect in a lot of cases, my device will sometimes be used in an under-water environment (or another fluid) where there will be a reaonable 'thickness' of fluid (up to ~100mm say) between the surface and the sensor - so IR is a no go. The fluid is likely to be up to 30°C warmer than the surface itself.

Any suggestions of other technologies (or even specific sensors) I should be considering? I'm not looking for amazing tolerances, maybe something comparable to an IR thermometer (~±0.5°C or better). My googling is not yielding anything, and my attempts to think through the physics aren't yielding any obvious mechanism by which one could assertain the temperature of an object at distance without measuring radiation...

Thanks

Edit: Added some application details.

Comment: Do you have any Specs ? Delta T, distance, tolerance?

Comment: Would you even expect a meaningful temperature difference between fluid and object? And if so, doesn't the temperature change (significantly) over time?

Comment: What's the range of temperatures you need to cover? What's the spatial "spot size" you need? How far above is the non-contact sensor to be (optical pyrometry?) Temperature is an emergent phenomenon from the large-number statistics. It conducts, convects, and radiates. That's it. So if you don't touch the material, you are doing pyrometry or phosphor thermometry or inventing some new idea based on your creativity, your knowledge and what you are examining. The surface requirement does offer some thoughts for selection (polarization pops to mind.) But then it's a long meeting to discuss.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 This is very early stage scoping of potential solutions, so the spec is very loose. Measuring temperatures down to around -55°C, where the device could be as warm as -20°C at times. Lets call distance from sensor to surface 1-100mm. Tolerance less than 1°C, comparable to a cheap IR thermometer (I can't see it being reasonable to ask for the same accuracy I would expect from a contact solution). Good question, I'll add these details into the question itself.

Comment: @LarsHankeln I think possibly a considerable difference, up to ~30°C. I do expect temperatures to change significantly over time, and taking measurements over time to capture this is likely to be desired.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the input. On your questions I've answered most here now, for 'spot-size' I wouldn't be fussy. It could be 1mm across or a few centimetres, I'm looking for average temperature of various regions of the surface, rather than of specific locations. Thanks for your inputs, I wasn't aware of pyrometric methods other than IR, and also didn't know about phosphor thermometry. While phosphor thermometry won't be suitable for this application, being maed aware of these various technologies is exactly what I was looing for.

Comment: @JRVeale Consider all physics associated with the problem. For example, if you can work out a way that scattering modes (matte, velvety, and specular) can be used -- then by all means use that to help yourself. Acceptance angle (sapphire has twice the acceptance of quartz, for example) might be another consideration. And on and on. The more you disclose, the more ideas that can be examined, tossed away, and the better what remains may apply.

Comment: Can you attach something to the object?  Maybe something like a label?